# Using NSUserDefaults to load data depending on which table view cell is pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I want my app to work just like the 'contacts' app on iOS. When a user selects a certain TableViewCell, i want to load certain data.

[image]

No Matter which cell is pressed, Either "Joseph, Richard, or Shannon", This view comes up:

[image]

[image]

Both of the views look the exact same, but they just display different information. So i guess my question is: How can I programmatically set a key @"cell1" @"cell2", etc... for each cell using NSUserDefaults? But here is the catch, I dont know how many cells will be added, so i cant hard code this, How can I create a key for each table view cell for how ever many is added? Thanks for the help!

Comment: its quite simple, use [indexpath row], its unique for each cell

Comment: right, that pertains to each row, it still doesn't quite help me wrap my head around how to create a key for each cell to store data in NSUserDefaults. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you don't want to use `NSUserDefaults`.... that's only used for persistant user information, such as preferences. It'd be better to use Core Data for that sort of thing.

One idea, since you want to tag the views, is to use the `-[UIView setTag:]` or `UIView.tag` property/method on the `UITableViewCell` during cell dequeueing. Using the `UITableView` delegate methods, you could detect a tap on the cell, retrieve its tag, and look up the `NSUserDefaults`, or better, your database.

The preferred way, is to keep an indexed database, dequeue a cell, and when it's tapped, navigate to the detail pane using the cell's index. This is a far more representative programming model, than tagging a view and using `NSUserDefaults` to pull the data.

Comment: okay, so since you say core data is my best bet... I have been through many core data tutorials in the past to try to learn, i have a basic understanding of core data. But i still need to learn more, could you recommend any good/quality tutorials? And what do you call this type of design pattern/model so i may google more on this topic? Thank you!

Comment: Model-View-Controller design pattern. It sits on the hinge of the Cocoa "Design Language" that Steve Jobs touts so well... there's also a ton of questions on Stack Overflow! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have your heart stuck on using `NSUserDefaults`, try this:

```
NSUserDefaults * prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
cellNumber = [prefs objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d", index]];
```

You can then save the max index so that you know exactly how many `UITableViewCells` you will have to display.

Keep in ming that there is a low storage limit for `NSUserDefaults`, so you may not be able to store all of your information there. You can find out more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating an NSMutableDictionary which stores key/value pairs for each cell than storing it in NSUserDefaults

```
NSMutableDictionay *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict forKey:@"myKey"];
[dict release];
```

than you can update the dictionary with cell values whenever you want:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myKey"];
[dict setValue:aNameforThisCell forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat@"cell%d", indexPath.row]];
```